# Critical Values of a Function

Tags: calculus, functions, optimization

I need to find the critical values of $h(t) = t^{3/4} - 2t^{1/4}.$

So I began by finding the derivative of the function and simplifying:

\begin{align*}
h'(t) &= (3/4)t^{-1/4} - (2/4)t^{-3/4} \\
&= \frac{3}{4t^{1/4}} - \frac{2}{4t^{3/4}}\\
&= \frac{3t^{3/4} - 2t^{1/4}}{4t}
\end{align*}

To find the first critical value, I set the denominator equal to 0 and got the first value of 0, but I'm stuck on the last critical value. The back of the book says the critical values are 0 and 4/9.

How can I go from here to find the 4/9 critical value?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Welcome to math.stackexchange! See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for a quick formatting tutorial, this will help your questions look more comprehensible. 

EDIT - I see you figured some of it out already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $$3t^{3\over 4}-2t^{1\over 4}=0.$$ Factoring out $t^{1\over 4}$ we obtain $$t^{1\over 4}(3t^{1\over 2}-2)=0.$$ We know that $t=0$ is a soltuion. So $$3t^{1\over 2}=2.$$ Squaring both sides we get $$9t=4.$$ Thus $$t={4\over 9}.$$

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the denominator to zero, that would give you a division by zero, which is undefined, rather than zero.

You always set the numerator equal to zero. Then note that $t=0$ will make the numerator zero, or, if $t\neq0$, then you can divide by $t$ and find $t=4/9$.

The $t=0$ case is called a trivial solution and is something to watch out for when solving any type of equation.

Comment: My book says otherwise. h'(t) does not exist when t = 0. Thus it is a critical number

Comment: My main question is that I am lost on how to obtain 4/9 from where I am so far in the problem

Comment: If the numerator is zero, $3t^{3/4} - 2t^{1/4}=0$, so $3t^{3/4} = 2t^{1/4}$. One solution to this is $t=0$. If $t$ is non-zero, I can divide by $t^{1/4}$ to get $3t^{1/2} = 2$, or $t^{1/2}=2/3$, which (squaring both sides) gives $t=4/9$. It has nothing to do with the denominator.

Comment: You're welcome.